# Python using random with if statements

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQq2K.png)

I tried making a sort of text-based game: but I haven't been able to get the first part to work - as it seems to ignore the statement qualifier and does the statement anyway or at least repeats it.
Help would be most appreciated.
Ignore the odds they are place holders.

````
import random
import math
php=30
while php>0:
    r=random.randint(1,10)
    if r==7:
        print("Found a room with a chest")
        o=input("do you open it?(Y/N)")
        t=random.randint(1,20)

        if o=="Y":
            l=random.randint(1,2)
            lq=random.randint(1,8)
            print(l,"item")
            print(lq,"quality")
            if l==1:
                item="weapon"
            if l==2:
                item="armour"

            if lq == 1 or 2:
                q="bad"
                print(lq,q)
                if item =="weapon":
                    d=random.randint(0,2)
                    dice=4
                    print(q)
                    print(random.randint(1,dice)+random.randint(1,dice)+d)

                if item =="health":
                    armour=random.randint(1,3)

            if lq == 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:
                q="good"
                print(lq,q)
                if item =="weapon":
                    da=random.randint(1,3)
                    dice=6
                    print(q)
                    print(random.randint(1,dice)+random.randint(1,dice)+d)

                if item =="armour":
                    armour=random.randint(2,6)

            if lq == 8:
                q="rare"
                print(lq,q)
                if item =="weapon":
                    d=random.randint(2,5)
                    dice=random.randint(6,8)
                    print(q)
                    print(random.randint(1,dice)+random.randint(1,dice)+d)

                if item =="armour":
                    armour=random.randint(4,8)
                ```
````

Comment: could you elaborate? show your code? the more info you give us the better we can help

Comment: code should be there "enter image description here"

Comment: have you tried using elif?

Comment: if (condition) elif (if not the before condition)

Comment: Would it make a difference? As it should still check the statement

Comment: yes it would because it would only and only if the before returned false

Comment: `if lq == 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:` should be `if lq == 3 or lq == 4 or lq == 5 or lq == 6 or lq == 7:`. What part of the code are you talking about when you say the statement qualifier doesn't work?

Comment: just an improvement, instead of doing `if lq == 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7`, you should make it `if lq >= 3 and lq <= 7`

Comment: and just put the code already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are places where you are not evaluating anything that could be falsey in some of your `if` statements.

For example, you have this line:

```
if lq == 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7
```

The values of `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7` are not expressions to evaluate; they are simply values, which causes python to enter the if block.

Instead, you will need to either break out the or statements into expressions to evaluate:

```
if lq == 3 or lq == 4 or lq == 5 or lq == 6 or lq == 7
```

Or, the more pythonic way, is to make use of `in` to check if a value is in a list (`in` can evaluate types other than a list, but that's not important right now). You would do it like this:

```
if lq in [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Edit:** Axiumin_ pointed out that this scenario of checking if your value is within a *range* (as opposed to discrete values) can be evaluated as simply as:

```
if lq >= 3 and lq <= 7
```

Another pythonic and simple way to evaluate a range, is to use the `range` function:

```
if lq in range(3, 7)
```

Comment: wouldn't `if lq >= 3 and lq <= 7` be better as its shorter (assuming its in a range)?

Comment: @Axiumin_ that's a good point, and I've edited that into the answer.